# regex to match on a person's name as enter

Tags: regex

I am trying to return a match if none of the following is found anywhere in the person's name when entered (case insensitive):

Dr
Dr.
Mr
Mr.
Mrs
Mrs.
Ms
Ms.
Miss
and
+
&
PHD
Sr
Sr.
Jr
Jr.

It also needs to look for spaces on either side of the above so as not non match "Drake" or "Missy", etc..

I'm not very good a regex and trying this in regexbuddy is also defficult..  Anyone here able to help out?  What I have so far works ok but on for the front of a string but someone could enter dennis dr dennis and be fine...

```
^\s*(?!(?:(\s*)Dr|Mr|Mrs|Miss|Ms)\b).*?$
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what language are you using? It might be an easier problem if you were to split your string on whitespace and inspect each of the resulting elements for the presence of titles, generationals, etc

Comment: For readability, I would also split this on whitespace and compare to a known list of prefixes and suffixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following regular expression:

```
/(?:^|\W)(?:(?:Dr|Mr|Mrs|Ms|Sr|Jr)\.?|Miss|Phd|\+|&)(?:\W|$)/i
```

#### EDIT: Alternative regex based on negative lookahead:

```
/(?!.*?(?:^|\W)(?:(?:Dr|Mr|Mrs|Ms|Sr|Jr)\.?|Miss|Phd|\+|&)(?:\W|$))^.*$/i
```

Comment: @citizen conn: Here is the working php code on ideone using above regex: http://ideone.com/n3j6S

Comment: I see, different approach, if it does match then you are calling it a match... BUT it is still matching the "DR" in "DrSmith" which would cause your script to fail

Comment: @citizen conn: For that all we need is to start and end regex with `\b`. Please check the ideone demo now: http://ideone.com/0HAg6 It will not match `DrSmith` now.

Comment: I tried adding the "+" to it but can't get it to match.. |\+|

Comment: Something like this should work: `/(?:^|\b)(?:(?:Dr|Mr|Mrs|Ms|Sr|Jr)\.?|Miss|Phd|\+)(?:\b|$)/i` If it doesn't please let me know the example string and I will test on my end.

Comment: Ok just got it working, try `/(?:^|\W)(?:(?:Dr|Mr|Mrs|Ms|Sr|Jr)\.?|Miss|Phd|\+)(?:\W|$)/i`

Comment: Its working now but now it returns a match on Dr. word+ word, etc..  How can it return a no-match?

Comment: @Dennis: Please see the demo here: http://ideone.com/7itk3 String `Dr. word+ word` is returning as non-match.

Comment: yes, your using php to switch the return.  I'm using jquery and that isn't possible since all my other regex's are returning a match (i.e. "Dennis" = match, "Dr. Dennis" = non-match

Comment: Can you pls paste your jquery code, I will try to provide you fix in that.

Comment: Not asking you to paste full code, just the snippet that does this regex match.

Comment: @Dennis: Posted an alternative regex in **EDIT** section above to do inverse of earlier regex. Also se demo at: http://ideone.com/xncWG

Comment: AWESOME dude!  If your ever in Ohio, pizza and beer is on me!

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks I will remember Pizza+Beer offer :) Really glad that it worked out for you eventually.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
^\s*(?!(?:Dr|Mr|Mrs|Miss|Ms)\.?\b)(?!.*\b(?:\+|&|PHD|Sr|Jr)(?:(?:\.\B)|\b)).*?$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u221)

I added a second part to your regex

```
(?!.*\b(?:\+|&|PHD|Sr|Jr)(?:(?:\.\B)|\b))
```

This looks for the things somewhere in the string with a word boundary before and after except when it ends with a dot then followed by a non word boundary.