# RegEx: Match Mr. Ms. etc in a "Title" Database field

Tags: regex

I need to build a RegEx expression which gets its text strings from the Title field of my Database. I.e. the *complete strings* being searched are: `Mr.` or  `Ms.` or `Dr.`  or `Sr.` etc.

Unfortunately this field was a free field and anything could be written into it. e.g.: `M.` ; `A` ; `CFO` etc.

The expression needs to match on everything except: `Mr.` ; `Ms.` ; `Dr.` ; `Sr.`  (NOTE: The list is a bit longer but for simplicity I keep it short.)

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR:**

This is what I am using successfully on on another field:

`^(?!(VIP)$).*`  (This will match every string except "VIP")

I rewrote that expression to look like this:

`^(?!(Mr.|Ms.|Dr.|Sr.)$).*`

Unfortunately this did not work.  I assume this is because because of the "." (dot) is a reserved symbol in RegEx and needs special handling.

I also tried:

`^(?!(Mr\.|Ms\.|Dr\.|Sr\.)$).*`

But no luck as well.

I looked around in the forum and tested some other solutions but could not find any which works for me.

I would like to know how I can build my formula to search the complete (short) string and matches everything **except** "Mr." etc. Any help is appreciated!

*Note: My Question might seem unusual and seems to have many open ends and possible errors. However the rest of my application is handling those open ends. Please trust me with this.*

Comment: Have you looked at  [this][1]. I can't comment or would've

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430464/regex-to-match-on-a-persons-name-as-enter

Comment: @Faruq: Thanks I did. It did not work unfortunately. Also it is designed to search longer strings. My strings are literally only the titles.

Comment: Which language tool are you using..Regex won't be suitable here

Comment: @Anirudh. Not sure to be honest. It is build into a database import utility which was most likely written in VB.net

Comment: Could you define 'that did not work'? What happened exactly when you used the regex you tried?

Comment: @Jerry: Thank you. The problem is that I am using a program which is quite specialized and I do not know how to explain it. But I will attempt: I am using a specialized import utility to get data into a database. This utility has something which is called a "Dictionary" which can be applied on a specific field to to translate and standardize the data from the source file before it gets saved. You specify the correct database value and then you give all the misspelling possibilities: Correct: Mr.  Source File: Mr., Mr, MR, Mister, etc.

Comment: Please ignore the above comment. I am rewriting it now in the next one:

Comment: @Jerry: Thank you. To answer your question: For some reason that formula does not match everything else. When I test to see if the formula matches, for example: "abc" it does not match it....The problem is that I am using a program which is quite specialized and I do not know how to explain it. But I will attempt: I am using a specialized import utility to get data into a database. This utility has something which is called a "Dictionary" which can be applied on a specific field to translate and standardize the data from the source file before it gets saved into the DB.

Comment: Part 2: You specify the correct database value and then you give all the misspelling possibilities: Correct: `Mr.`  Source File Values: `Mr.`, `Mr`, `MR`, `Mister`, etc. This is done through the front end and does not require a RegEx. However I have also the possibility to use regular expressions: Correct Value: --Blank-- Source File Values:  ^(?!(Mr.|Ms.|Dr.|Sr.)$).*. This Regular expression is supposed to match on everything  except Mr.|Ms etc and then have the Dictionary return a ZeroString or NULL or whatever. I hope this makes at least somewhat sense...

Comment: Part 3: FYI. I also posted this question at the Vendor's forum  who created the program but there is not much activity like on SO....

Comment: Ok. I find it strange that `^(?!(VIP)$).*` works but something like `abc` as you describe doesn't... And I'm sorry but I still don't know what you're getting as "does not match everything else" :s Does that mean that you're getting all results? Or are some Mr not chosen but others chosen? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

If you want your string simply to not *start* with one of those prefixes, then do this:

```
^(?!([MDS]r|Ms)\.).*$
```

The above simply ensures that the beginning of the string (`^`) is *not* followed by one of your listed prefixes. (You shouldn't even need the `.*$` but this is in case you're using some engine that requires a complete match.)

If you want your string to not have those prefixes *anywhere*, then do:

```
^(.(?!([MDS]r|Ms)\.))*$
```

The above ensures that every character (`.`) is *not* followed by one of your listed prefixes, to the end (so the `$` *is* necessary in this one).

---

I just read that your list of prefixes may be longer, so let me expand for you to add:

```
^(.(?!(Mr|Ms|Dr|Sr)\.))*$
```

---

You say *entirely* of the prefixes? Then just do this:

```
^(?!Mr|Ms|Dr|Sr)\.$
```

And if you want to make the dot conditional:

```
^(?!Mr|Ms|Dr|Sr)\.?$
                  ^
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. What you say about my VIP formula is correct behavior. Only I put the "VIP" expression as an example which worked in a different scenario. My current strings consist ONLY of : `MR`   or `A`  or `Ms.`...Yes, the formula needs to check the complete string as a whole. Also, I edited my question to make it hopefully more clear

Comment: Ah, then I misunderstood, sorry; I'll remove that bit.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried the new expressions. It still does not work. It just might be that the application I am using is too specialized. I posted this question also on the Vendor's forum. So hopefully I get an answer tomorrow when they come in. I can let you know what they say.

Answer (score 2):

Through this `|` we can define any number prefix pattern which we gonna match with string.

```
var pattern = /^(Mrs.|Mr.|Ms.|Dr.|Er.).?[A-z]$/;
var str = "Mrs.Panchal";
console.log(str.match(pattern));
```

Answer (score 0):

this may do it

```
/(?!.*?(?:^|\W)(?:(?:Dr|Mr|Mrs|Ms|Sr|Jr)\.?|Miss|Phd|\+|&)(?:\W|$))^.*$/i
```

from that page I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to construct a regex that matches anything **except** `Mr.`, `Ms.`, etc., it would be easier (if your application allows it) to write a regex that matches **only** those strings:

```
/^(Mr|Ms|Dr|Sr)\.$/
```

and just swap the logic for handling matching vs non-matching strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub(r'^([MmDdSs][RSrs]{1,2}|[Mm]iss)\.{0,1} ','',name)
```

Comment: Please add some description to your code explaining what is going on and why. This is good practice. If you don't, your answer is in risk of being deleted. It has already been flagged as low quality.